# Database size on disk increases as a multiple of the CSV file I mongoimport?

Tags: mongodb, csv, import

I imported a CSV file which is 230M in total size, the dimensions of the file are 3069055 rows and 13 columns.

The command I used to import was:

mongoimport -d taq -c mycollection --type csv --file myfile.csv --headerline

Before I did this import the taq database was empty. After the import completed (which took 4 minutes), I checked the size of the database files in the mongodb user directory. This is what I see:

```
-rw------- 1 mongod mongod  64M Jul 23 14:13 taq.0  
-rw------- 1 mongod mongod 128M Jul 23 14:10 taq.1 
-rw------- 1 mongod mongod 256M Jul 23 14:11 taq.2
-rw------- 1 mongod mongod 512M Jul 23 14:13 taq.3 
-rw------- 1 mongod mongod 1.0G Jul 23 14:13 taq.4 
-rw------- 1 mongod mongod 2.0G Jul 23 14:13 taq.5
-rw------- 1 mongod mongod  16M Jul 23 14:13 taq.ns
```

Six taq files have been created, numbered from 0 to 5. The total size of these files is multiple GBs. Why is this, when the CSV file I imported is only 230M? Is this a bug? Or am I missing something?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB stores data in a totally different format, called BSON, which is going to take up more disk space. Not only do the values need to be stored for each field, it also will have to store the column names again in each document (row). If you have large column names, this can definitely increase the size in MongoDB to be 8 to 10 times of your CSV file. If possible, you can look at shortening your field names if this is too much for you.

MongoDB also **preallocates** data files for you. For example, the moment it starts adding data to `taq.2`, it will create `taq.3`, and similarly when it starts writing into `taq.4` it creates `tag.5`. So in your case, say your 230MB file would create 1.9GB of data, MongoDB has already allocated the 2.0G sized `taq.5`. This behaviour can be turned off by specifying `--noprealloc` on the command line when starting `mongod`.

Comment: So apart from the preallocation, the main reason for the increased size is that every document is storing a copy of the field names.   My dataset is already very big in CSV format..... with MongoDB inflating the size by almost a factor of 10 that means MongoDB is going to quickly eat up available disk space. Is there any way around this (apart from making field names shorter)? I see this as a major issue.

Comment: Since my last post I have developed my experience with MongoDB and the disk space issue isn't as serious as I originally suspected. I have also minimized the length of my field names. All is good now.Thanks for your help.