# mongodb data size increased around 6 times

Tags: mongodb

Imported about 5.3 GB of data from csv file ( 20 million rows)

Below is the result of data import:-

2015-12-24T17:21:14.178-0500    [#######################.] abhishek.test        5.3 GB/5.3 GB (100.0%)

When checked in mongodb it showed 37.84GiB. I don't have any replication factor in place. So not sure why data increased about 6 times.

Totals
data : 37.84GiB docs : 20000000 chunks : 1295

Shard shard0000 contains 50.51% data, 50.51% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 1KiB

Shard shard0001 contains 49.48% data, 49.48% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 1KiB

( I am a novice in mongodb. )

Comment: See [Database size on disk increases as a multiple of the CSV file I mongoimport?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17811853/database-size-on-disk-increases-as-a-multiple-of-the-csv-file-i-mongoimport)

Comment: Thanks for pointing the URL. I will try decreasing the column name length and check for the datasize.